# Order by count(*) subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

Completely new to subqueries, I'm trying to order posts from table `showcase` by the number of comments they have (in descending order) and not sure how.

```
SELECT *
FROM showcase
ORDER BY 
    (select count(*)
     from comments)
DESC
```

Comment: There is no relation between showcase and comments in your query.

Comment: Better give the table structute

Comment: comments has `item_id`, which is `id` in showcase

Comment: `SELECT *
FROM showcase as s
ORDER BY 
    (select count(*)
     from comments as c where s.id=c.item_id)
DESC`    is it that?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the ids, group by and count rows for each group

```
select showcase.id
from showcase left join comments on comments.item_id = showcase.id
group by showcase.id
order by count(showcase.id) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to use group by along with count:

```
select s.postId, count(c.commentid) as comments
from showcase s join comment c on s.postId = c.postId
group by s.postId
order by comments desc
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can try a join query which is better for query.

```
SELECT `showcase`.*, count(`comments`.`item_id`) as item_id FROM `showcase`
LEFT JOIN `comments`
ON `showcase`.`id`, `comments`.`item_id`
ORDER BY item_id DESC
```

Let me know is it work or not.